# How to dismiss current form in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Hi i'm new to codenameone and now i stuck with two issues those are

1. How to dismiss current form in codenameone?

   It means that in my sample i've three screens and when i click on button in Form1 it navigates to the Form2 like that Form2 to Form3 also. now when i click back button on Form3/Form2 i want to dismiss current form. so for this i've tried "showBack() method" but its not working.

   So could anyone help me for this? and
2. How to show Calendar in Current form?

   I want to show Calendar in current form but i've tried multiple samples but in all samples when i click on button they taking to another screen(i.e. Another Form). so how to resolve this also?

These are my questions if anyone has idea please help me..

Sorry for my poor English..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Form.showBack() is almost the same as Form.show(). It uses the back transition instead of forward one.
For your case, you have to call showBack() on the form that should be displayed.

Example:
Form1 is currently visible
Form2.showBack() is executed
Form 2 will be shown with a back transition

Comment: Thanks Hatti.. Its working.. sorry for late reply.. any solution for 2nd question in above post..

Answer (score 0):

For question 2: `form.add(new Calendar(new Date().getTime()));`

Comment: Thanks for reply..i tried your code It showing calendar but its not showing correctly and that too it showing normal calendar, is it possible show material calendar?